# Google Swiffy: Will it fall back to Flash where HTML5 is not supported?

Tags: flash, google-swiffy

Swiffy is a tool by Google that automatically converts SWF files to HTML5.  It gives good results, but I wonder if a page containing Swiffy code is requested on a device that has Flash Player installed but does not support HTML5, what happens?

Ideally they will simply get the old SWF file instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the check and fallback yourself